# Does a Realm table have a size limitation?

Tags: realm

Is there a limit for table size?
I need to add new data in average once every second.
I'm saving information from a bluetooth device so i will get an update every second that the app is in foreground/background.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realm uses memory mapping to access the file. Depending on the OS, the virtual address space per process is limited. In our experience this is the limit, you'll likely hit first.

The good news is you can still have millions of objects.

But for a really large Realm database, you have to be careful about concurrent access, because the file must be memory-mapped once per thread with the current architecture in our underlying storage engine. This has implications to our bindings. When you have a lot of concurrent writes and your accessors keep retained for long time, you're more likely to hit the limits.
For that reason, we usually recommend to write from a single thread and batch writes to large transactions. By doing that you can prevent creating many intermediate versions, which must be also retained in the file and so cause further unwanted file growth.

You can reduce the size a Realm database occupies by using the `compact` methods. This must be only used as long as that file is not opened by other accessors.